# Turn filter on by default on a sharepoint view

Tags: filter, view

I would like to filter a column defaultly on my SharePoint view, is it possible to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are referring to the regular SharePoint View from a list, you
   could modify the View under Library - Modify View so that you
   include that value, which would be applied for all users in the "Public View" (or create a Personal View for yourself).
2. If by "filter" you mean to be able to FILTER dynamically you could
   use any of the Filter Web Parts enabling you filtering (there are quite a few available depending on your license type)!
3. If you want to go wilder (more specific), use SharePoint Designer, insert an Data
   View Web Part and enable Filtering capabilities in that web part. As
   a result for all columns you will get filter based on values
   available

Comment: I think they meant 'can we have a normal column-header filter on by default, but still be able to turn it off', rather than blocking everything from the database side like a view filter. This would be ideal for e.g. a task list where you initially want to exclude completed items but might want to turn them back on occasionally. Having to make another view just to change the filter is overworked and a headache for maintenance. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably add ?Filter=1 
example:
https://contoso.com/sites/HR/employees/AllItems.aspx?filter=1